# Is there any way for me to speed up jQuery excution on a static webpage?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, netlify, static-site, page-load-time

I'm building a portfolio with [semplice](https://www.semplice.com/). It's a fancy Wordpress theme but I really want to host it through Netlify as a static site. I've generated a static version but Its performance is terrible. Lighthouse reports jQuery is the main culperate adding 1.5/2 seconds onto load time. I've tried to defer it but this makes no difference. Is there anything I can do to improve the site's performance or is there a good reson no one else seems to have done this?

My site is https://www.ajalong.com/. Any insight would be amazing, Thanks!